# Python setup.py error: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, pip, transformer-model

I am trying to build the Transformer Grammars code here: https://github.com/google-deepmind/transformer_grammars/tree/main

I am running a Google Cloud Deep Learning VM, N1 instance, TensorFlow 2.10 (CUDA 11.3, Python 3.7).

Here is the contents of the `install.sh` file that I am trying to run:

```
set verbose
set -o errexit

rm -rf .dependencies
mkdir .dependencies
cd .dependencies
git clone -b 20220623.1 https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp.git
git clone -b 3.4.0 https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen.git
git clone -b v2.10.2 https://github.com/pybind/pybind11.git

sudo apt-get install cmake build-essential pkg-config libgoogle-perftools-dev
git clone -b v0.1.97 https://github.com/google/sentencepiece.git
cd sentencepiece
mkdir build
cd build
make -j
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig -v

cd ../../..
pip install --require-hashes -r requirements.txt
pip install -e . --no-deps --no-index

rm -rf .dependencies
```

The error text reads:

```
error in transformer_grammars setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Invalid requirement, parse error at "'\\'"
```

In the `setup()` command in setup.py, the code pertaining to `install_requires` reads

```
install_requires=dependencies
```

and `dependencies` is gotten as

```
with open("requirements.txt", "r") as f:
     dependencies = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), f.readlines()))
```

Notably, this is at the bottom of `requirements.txt`:

```
# WARNING: The following packages were not pinned, but pip requires them to be
# pinned when the requirements file includes hashes. Consider using the --allow-unsafe flag.
# setuptools
```

I don't really know what this means but assumed it might be relevant because other posts I've seen that have a similar error to this involve setuptools.

Things I have tried to no avail:

- Upgrading pip
- Upgrading setuptools
- Reverting to an older version of setuptools (39.1.0)
- Contacting relevant people at DeepMind

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the contents of `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely because of the comments or other extra information in your requirements.txt file. Make sure the file is [formatted correctly](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/), and then try this:

```py
def parse_req_line(s: str) -> str:
    s = s.strip().replace("\n", "")
    return "" if len(s) < 2 or s.startswith("#") else s

with open("requirements.txt", "r") as f:
     dependencies = [d for l in f.readlines() if (d := parse_req_line(l))]
```